# How to add multiple business hours in fullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there any way to set multiple business hours, or grey out certain time ranges in FullCalendar's agenda view? I'm searching the google for hours, but I didn't find any working answer.

Here's what I've tried:

```
businessHours:
        [
        {
         start: '08:00', 
         end: '17:00', 
         dow: [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]

         },
         {
         start: '10:00', 
         end: '16:00', 
         dow: [ 6 ]

         }]
```

This is not working. The fullcalendar recognizes this array as a true value, and sets the default value of businesHours.

This works:

```
 businessHours:

        {
         start: '08:00', 
         end: '17:00', 
         dow: [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]

         }
```

But I want to be able to customize every day's opening hours. Is there any way to solve this? If I could add somehow a css class to certain time ranges that would do it, but I don't know how to grab these time ranges. Render doesn't work, because of agenda view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out a solution. It is not the best way, to solve this problem, but it is easy to understand and implement, until we don't get a more customizable businessHours() function in an upcoming update.

The code:

```
events: [
    {
        start: '00:00:00+02:00',
        end: '08:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
    },

    {
        start: '16:00:00+02:00',
        end: '24:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
    },

    {
        start: '00:00:00+02:00',
        end: '8:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [6]
    },

    {
        start: '12:00:00+02:00',
        end: '24:00:00+02:00',
        color: 'gray',
        rendering: 'background',
        dow: [6]
    }
]
```

This will put background events in the Calendar, which are not clickable, and looks like `businessHours()`'s gray out, and will change the background color of every slot in **agendaWeek** and **agendaDay** from 00:00 to 08:00, 16:00 to 24:00 (from Mondays to Fridays - `dow:[1,2,3,4,5]`), and from 00:00 to 08:00, 12:00 to 24:00 (On Saturdays - `dow:[6]`).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much ☺

Answer (score 2):

You can add each business hour as an event.  `FullCalendar` works with the same structure to populate `businessHours` option:

```
{
  ...
  events: [
    // business hours 1
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '09:00',
        end: '17:00',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4], // monday - thursday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    },
    // business hours 2
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '15:00',
        dow: [6], // saturday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    }],
 ...
}
```

**Note**: The important `options` in this `events` are `className:'fc-nonbusiness` and `rendering:'inverse-background'`.

Good Luck.